# Jmeter Sampler Parameters: why do I get Array index out of range when accessing second parameter?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

Case:
Sampler Parameters:

> ${uuid}${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,1)}

Where

- ${uuid} : Extractor from previous sampler
- ${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,0)} : variable from file1 column1
- ${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,1)} : variable from file1 column2

When I try to get these variables, I get:

> "2018-09-07 13:27:37,841 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Array index out of range: 1"

Code:

```
var uuid = WDS.args[0]
var candidate = WDS.args[1];
var candidate2 = WDS.args[2];
```

Then I try to use candidate and candidate2 as string for

```
 WDS.browser.sendkeys()
```

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no space between your sampler parameters:

> ${uuid}${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,1)}

As such , you only have 1 parameter

Add a space between each of them and it will work:

> ${uuid} ${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,0)} ${__CSVRead(D:/apache-jmeter-4.0/WorkSpace/CandidatesForAssign.csv,1)}